# Unable to setup passwordless login to localhost & also ssh into localhost with password

Tags: linux, ssh

Debug information when I try to SSH into local host

## ssh root@localhost -vvv output

OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

Comment: Questions generally end with a '?'... All I see is that `localhost` either is not running `sshd`, or it is configured to not accept connections from that client for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the implications of passwordless login,

Connection refused suggests sshd is not started.  Check if sshd is running.

```
$ netstat -an|fgrep LIST|fgrep :22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

If not:

```
$ sudo systemctl status sshd
$ sudo systemctl enable sshd
$ sudo systemctl start sshd
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want passwordless ssh login "Safely",.. use a rsa or dsa-sshkey to login.

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id $user@$ip
```

login again no password :)